# Can I use adfs on a vb.net web form application

Tags: vb.net, web, webforms, adfs

I have an old vb.net web form app from around 2012.  The goal is to utilize adfs to allow for authentication.  Am I able to a) update the app as is and incorporate adfs or b) do I need to convert app to c# app, then incorporate adfs?  I have been searching online for some time and not finding anything relating to question part a).

Comment: I'm guessing you're finding C# examples & documentation.  If that is the case, they should be convertible to vb.net so to answer a) yeah, should be ok.  b) it's really up to you. IMO if you are looking at a rebuild it may very well be worth considering C# but it really comes down to the knowledge and experience of you and your team

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and I [did it](https://nzpcmad.blogspot.com/2014/02/visual-basic-vb-claims-enabled.html?m=1) a long time ago.

However, the links in the article no longer exist and it used an old version of VS.

VS 2010 used a tool called FedUtil that generated the web.config for you and this used the WIF library that used WS Federation to talk to ADFS.

But the WIF download link no longer works.

Depending on the ADFS version you have, there are C# samples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/single-page-application-with-ad-fs). Look under the ADAL and MSAL tags on the LHS.

You can add a C# dll to a VB project so you may be able to do just the auth. in C# and leave the rest in VB.